# Blender open a hyperlink by clicking on object

Tags: python, url, hyperlink, blender

Is it possible to dynamically open a web page by clicking on an object?
If so, how can this be accomplished?
What about linking to the underlying file system?
I'm using custom attributes to save the URLs, but have no way of calling them up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `webbrowser`?

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open('http://thisisaurl.org')
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Unfortunately I didn't know about it. I learned more than I bargained for. I not only have the information I was after, I have [re]-discovered how much the libraries that come with Blender have to offer when we remember to look there. ;)